# Customize first page of category

Tags: archives

I want to create a custom category page, only for the first page, displaying an article, related posts, latest posts. How can I do that?

Comment: That is a great solution. I am still learning the first steps of coding. So could you please explain where do I insert that code and what I should use in the field "Include your custom theme here". Thanks

Comment: You can add the code in your index.php or archive.php but in general on every site where you use a paginated loop. It depends on the theme you are using. Just put your custom Code (like a banner or something else) between the first two brackets.  "Include your custom theme here"  is just static placeholder text. You can display any kind of html or php functions there.

Answer (score 2):

I don´t think you can do this within the template overwrite structure of wordpress but you can include a custom template based on the pagination number.

```
if(get_query_var('paged') == 0){
 echo "Include your custom theme here";
}else{
 echo "standard";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was using category description field in Wordpress to create a custom page, and limit the number os posts in the first page of some categories for 8, keeping 16 on the remaining pages

```
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_main_query() || is_admin() ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( ! is_paged() && is_category(array (2 , 3) )) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 8 );
    }
} );
```